# How to Deploy Blazor Webassembly Web Application to Azure?

Tags: azure, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly

I have created a Blazor `Webassembly` web application with the PWA feature. It is a CRUD application.

This is my folder structure:

[image: structure]

Now I want to deploy it to azure. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server app is just an ordinary ASP.NET Core application (this is the app that needs to be published). You have several options, like publishing the app to an Azure App Service or an Azure virtual machine. The former would require you to prepare a Docker image (usually a good start would be to enable Docker support for the server project and tweak the created Dockefile to your needs).

Just read the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-5.0 to get the full picture.